# plot two subscripts on the same line one with prime

Tags: r, plot, latex, mathtype

I am trying to code using some math type for plotting using `expression(paste())`,

if I want `alpha` to have the subscript `sub1` I can do:

```
expression(paste(alpha[sub1]))
```

if i want to prime the subscript I can do:

```
expression(paste(alpha[sub1^"'"]))
```

but i can't figure out how to add another subscript after the `sub1`, so the subscript reads `alpha[sub1'sub2]` i.e. `sub1'sub2` is all in one line, at the same level.

I tried

```
expression(paste(alpha[sub1^"'"sub2]))
```

and

```
expression(paste(alpha[sub1^"'"],[sub2]))
```

It is easy to do without the prime however...

```
expression(paste(alpha[sub1sub2]))
```

I think this might be a case for `{}` but I can't find any examples that work through this. How can i do this with a prime for `sub1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all there is no need for `paste()` here. Secondly, you can use "*" to essentially place values beside each other. Try

```
expression(alpha[sub1^"'"*sub2])
```